# why the stop-cluster.sh stop the latest started Flink cluster?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm plan to do an upgrading from Flink 1.5.2 to 1.6.0, and then do the jobs migration. In order to minimum the pause time for the jobs, I plan to run both Flink clusters at the same time, after migrating jobs successfully, I  would stop the old one. However when I tried to stop the Flink  cluster by running stop-cluster.sh in the directory Flink1.5.2/bin  , I found the stopped cluster is Flink 1.6.0 instead of the expected Flink 1.5.2 .

I did some test and found the stop-cluster.sh just stop the latest started Flink cluster, that is to say, if you start cluster 1.6.0 firstly, then starts Flink 1.5.2, after that when you run stop-cluster.sh, it would stop Flink 1.5.2 firstly even you run the stop-cluster.sh at the cluster 1.6.0 directory Flink1.6.0/bin. Based on my understanding, when running the stop-cluster.sh at the Flink1.6.0/bin it should stop cluster 1.6.0, and stop the cluster 1.5.2 when running the stop-cluster.sh at the Flink1.5.2/bin , however it didn't.

I did some research and found the stop-cluster.sh would kill the process based on the file which contains the pid , however I don't know the location of that file, and I suspect both of the clusters write the pid in the same places when they started, which make the stop-cluster.sh chaotic.

Please advise how to stop the specified cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per default, the pid file is written to `/tmp` and has the name `flink-<USER>-<FLINK_COMPONENT>.pid`. You can control the directory by setting the `env.pid.dir` configuration in `flink-conf.yaml`. By using different pid file directory you can keep control over the different clusters.

Comment: Worked, however this important configuration item is un document:-)

Comment: Can you create a JIRA issue in order to fix this bug?

Comment: I created the JIRA , please assign it to me if possible:) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-10274